# Progress during AjaX call displays only initial and final value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, progress

I need to execute an AjaX call to a PHP script with a long execution time. My goal is to display a progress status of this execution.

The idea is to create an AjaX call to periodically ask the server about the status of the execution. The progress status is stored into `$_SESSION['progress']`, initially set to `0` and changed from script during execution.

Here's my code on client and server side.

**Client-side**

```
// invoke the script (ie. with button)
$('#start').click(function()
{
    $.ajax
    ({
        url: "long-script.php"
    });
});

// check progress periodically
setInterval(progress, 100);
function progress() 
{ 
    $.ajax
    ({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "progress.php",

        success: function(data) 
        {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

**long-script.php**

```
// just an example to emulate execution
sleep(1);
$_SESSION['progress']=30;
sleep(1);
$_SESSION['progress']=70;
sleep(1);
$_SESSION['progress']=100;
```

**progress.php**

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($_SESSION['progress']);
```

The problem is that `console.log()` in progress function outputs `0` before the script execution, stops outputing data during the execution, and finally outputs `100` when the script is terminated. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the session is not written, until the script ends, or the session closes.

You need to remember that sessions, by default in php are stored as files on the system and is locked in run-time.

What you can do is change the `long-script.php` file a bit.

```
session_start();

sleep(1);
$_SESSION['progress']=30;
session_write_close();

sleep(1);
session_start();
$_SESSION['progress']=70;
session_write_close();

sleep(1);
session_start();
$_SESSION['progress']=100;
session_write_close();
```

The idea is to write to the session after every progress changes.

Then you will need to start the session again.

This may be a wrong way to do this, but you can always look up the session functions in php. Take a look at this [session_write_cloe](http://php.net/session_write_close)

Comment: While this directly addresses the issue with the session not being written, it does not mention that there are probably FAR better ways to accomplish what the OP wants without using $_SESSION like this.

Comment: @cale_b not arguing there. Just wanted to show OP a work-around his method.

Comment: @cale_b: "there are probably FAR better ways to accomplish...". If you have better suggestions, I'm glad to hear about them.

Comment: One method: http://stratosprovatopoulos.com/web-development/php/ajax-progress-php-script-without-polling/ (I'm not a fan of the iFrame solution he references).  Another method: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/php/show-progress-report-for-long-running-php-scripts.html - and lastly, another method: if your "long" php script is inserting into the database, your "monitor" script could check the DB for progress and respond with that information.

Comment: Thanks. I will investigate about them.